# Make a built in class COM visible

Tags: javascript, vb.net, com, communication, point

I need to make a the Point structure COM visible so I can parse it to my javascript. At the moment, I have been creating copies of lists, well like in this guide:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication

Using Implements but I can't Implement a point (I have no idea what Implement actually does) but I have created a bunch of classes for my custom classes.

But I have a bunch of points which I want to parse to my javascript functions. Really I just need a way to get points into javascript or arrays if worse comes to worse. I've been googling to see if there was a way to apply the  _ (I use this on my custom class lists) to built in classes but found nothing. If I could do that, wow it would help so much, but I'm sure theres some big problem with doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to return a`Point` structure from your VB.NET COM object to javascript, you can return a custom COM-visible VB class serving for same purpose, something like below. You could then access its X and Y properties from javascript. A similar way, you can create another class like `VbPointArray` to return an array of `VbPoint`.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)> _
Public Class VbPoint
    Private _x As Integer
    Private _y As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
        _x = x
        _y = y
    End Sub

    Public Property X() As Integer
    Get
        Return _x
    End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Y() As Integer
    Get
        Return _y
    End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I actually totally forgot about this question, but this is an excellent answer which I will use in the future.